# Missing "Connected SharePoint Sites" settings

Tags: 2016, project-server, site-settings

I am using MS Project Server 2016 deployed on Windows 2019. I want to automatically create a site when a project is created. As per the documentation, this can be done using the *Settings* menu in *Connected Sharepoint Sites* page. However, I cannot find that option on my page. Please let me know how to enable it.
[image]

My site:
I am looking for this option:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you're still looking for the answer. But Microsoft removed this feature to a different location. It is now part of the project creation. You will have to modify the New Project template when creating an enterprise project. I tried it and it worked for me.

Below is the link to the article:

https://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/connected-sharepoint-site-settings-moved/